# Setting mouse position without System.Windows.Forms

Tags: c#, windows, mouse

Is there a way to manipulate the mouse position without using System.Windows.Forms.Cursor? Something like interop maybe?

Reason for this is that we are using a specialized .NET subset which can't include System.Windows.Forms.

Comment: Check this out, this is what the asker in this question does.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339565/send-mouse-keyboard-events

Comment: Yes, something like interop.  Pinvoke SetCursorPos().

Comment: What kind of subset is that? Does it include WPF or WinRT or something like that?

Comment: It's cut down. This is why I was thinking of interop, which indeed was  the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

oops my bad, read question too fast, heres the correct PInvoke call

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);
```

Source: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setcursorpos

Comment: I'm looking to set the position, so I need http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setcursorpos

Comment: Actually what I really wanted is http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.ClipCursor, I just didn't know something like that would exist! Life is good.

Answer (score -3):

```
private void MoveCursor()
{
   // Set the Current cursor, move the cursor's Position,
   // and set its clipping rectangle to the form. 

   this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
   Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - 50, Cursor.Position.Y - 50);
   Cursor.Clip = new Rectangle(this.Location, this.Size);
}
```

Comment: The following code example creates a cursor from the Current cursor's Handle, changes its position and clipping rectangle. The result is the cursor will move up and to the left 50 pixels from where it is when the code is executed. Additionally, the cursor's clipping rectangle is changed to the bounds of the form (by default it is the user's whole screen). This example requires a Form and a Button to call this code when it is clicked.

Comment: The question states that the System.Windows.Forms.Cursor cannot be used.