# C# How to create a mouse pointer after restart?

Tags: c#, windows, pointers, automation

I'm writing a program to test WIN10 settings automatically .The steps are as below:

1.Restart the computer.
 2.Change style of mouse pointer.
 3.Screen capture.

I've found there's no mouse pointer after restart computer.
Because it must be automation, so I need to create a mouse pointer by program.

I've tried : [Setting mouse position without System.Windows.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092784/setting-mouse-position-without-system-windows-forms)

But it doesn't worked.
And I tried :

```
System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = new System.Drawing.Point(500, 500);
```

Failed, too.
Is there any way to create a mouse pointer?

Comment: Why don't you post-process your screenshot image, and manually add a mouse pointer? As far as I know, the mouse pointer never shows up in screenshots.

Comment: I use this method [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750056/how-to-capture-the-screen-and-mouse-pointer-using-windows-apis   
 to let screenshots has a mouse pointer.

Comment: Are you trying to take a screenshot of the current standard cursor, or are you trying to get the code you copied (and failed to understand) to do what you expect?

Comment: I'm trying to get the mouse pointer show up automatically after restart the computer, but the code I use which is in my question didn't work as I expect it to.

Comment: Why are you trying to make the cursor show up? Is it because you don't know any other way to render a screenshot including the currently selected default cursor? It sure sounds like it.

Comment: YES! I don't know any other way to render a screenshot including the currently selected default cursor.